# combining Date and Time fields to DateTime, SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Ok - I've asked a few people and there has got to be an easy way to do this....

```
declare @Date date
declare @Time time 
declare @datetime datetime

select @Date = convert(Date,GetDate()) 
select @Time = convert(Time,GetDate())

select @Date, @Time, @Date + @Time (+ operator fails!)
```

Do I really have to: 
1) convert to a string, then convert to datetime field?
2) use DateAdd and DatePart to add hours first then minutes, then seconds.....

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question, this is a question about the new Date and Time types in SQL 2008. The other question does not involve these at all and is all about DateTime types.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
@Date + cast(@Time as datetime)
```

In SQL Server 2012 and I assume SQL Server 2014 you neeed to cast both the date and the time variable to datetime.

```
cast(@Date as datetime) + cast(@Time as datetime)
```

Comment: Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The data types date and datetime are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: Agreed, Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: The data types date and datetime are incompatible in the add operator. You need to cast both as datetime as pointed out by @jdavies.

Comment: @mprost Not in SQL Server 2008 but in SQL Server 2012 you are correct. And also presumably in SQL Server 2014. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with `datetime2` or other datetime types?

Comment: @jocull Have a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51440/how-to-combine-date-and-time-to-datetime2-in-sql-server/51443#51443

Answer (score 13):

Try casting them both to DATETIME first:

```
SELECT CAST(@Date AS DATETIME) + CAST(@Time AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Correct is the non-deterministic form: ALTER TABLE MyTable 
ADD MyDateTime2 AS 
(
 DATEADD
 (
   day 
  ,DATEDIFF
  (
    day
   ,CONVERT( DATE, '19000101', 112)
   , mydate
  )
  ,CONVERT(datetime2(7), mytime)
 )
) PERSISTED

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
select @Date, @Time, CAST(@Date AS datetime) + CAST(@Time AS datetime)
```