# How to get Last two hours Records From SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Date(2017-01-07) and Time(23:58:06 PM) Two Column, i have tried the below Query

```
SELECT * FROM Report WHERE Time > DATEADD(HOUR, -2, GETDATE())
```

Time is NVARCHAR, DATE is Date

But i am getting the Error Called "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Please Help me to get this solved!!! i am a SQL Starter

Comment: what datatype is the `Time` column? Can you show DDL/schema, so we get the idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Time is a TEXT field.

You should consider to combine Date and Time to get a DateTime field, and then use it in the WHERE clause.

This answer in SO could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7289875/3270427

```
SELECT * 
FROM Report 
WHERE CAST(Date AS DATETIME) + CAST(Time AS DATETIME) >= DATEADD(HOUR, -2, GETDATE());
```

Comment: i am using Time column as NVARCHAR it contains both AM/PM.

Comment: Yes as per your suggestion i have combined the date and time field and now this query is working good...! thank you..!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is add them together and then compare to get date.  Unfortunately, you cannot add a `date` and `time` together.  Happily, you can add a `datetime` and `time` together.

So:

```
WHERE (CAST(date as datetime) + time) >= DATEADD(HOUR, -2, GETDATE())
```

If `time` is character, then you should be able to convert that as well:

```
WHERE (CAST(date as datetime) + CAST(time as time)) >= DATEADD(HOUR, -2, GETDATE())
```

Or, if the PM is redundantly part of the `time`, then:

```
WHERE (CAST(date as datetime) + CAST(LEFT(time, 8) as time)) >= DATEADD(HOUR, -2, GETDATE())
```

Unfortunately, this will not use an index.  But, one simple method is to use a computed column and an index:

```
alter table report add datetimecol as (CAST(date as datetime) + time);
create index idx_report_datetimecol on report(datetimecol);
```

EDIT:

You seem to have a problem with your data.  Try:

```
select time
from report
where try_convert(time, timecol) is null;
```

or:

```
select time
from report
where try_convert(time, left(timecol, 8)) is null;
```

If the date column is also a string (really bad idea to not use native data types), then test that as well.

Comment: Thanks for you Valuable  reply, but still im getting the same error with this error(Column 'datetimecol' in table 'Report' cannot be used in an index or statistics or as a partition key because it is non-deterministic.), this table is updating every 5mins continuously using script, so what i did for time being is select top 300 rows to show the last 2hours report.

Comment: @T.Anand . . . Well, at least you are learning the lesson to use built-in datatypes.  They are there for a reason.  You now have to search for mis-structured strings.