# SQL: How to get the actual shift values

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssms

I´ve created a report in SSRS in which I display all Machines volume from 
last hour:

```
where  IntervalStartDateTime >= dateadd(HOUR, -2, GETDATE())
    And IntervalStartDateTime <= dateadd(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())
```

from last 4 hours:

```
where  IntervalStartDateTime >= dateadd(HOUR, -4, GETDATE())
    And IntervalStartDateTime <= dateadd(HOUR, -3, GETDATE())
```

and from last 8 hours:

```
where  IntervalStartDateTime >= dateadd(HOUR, -8, GETDATE())
    And IntervalStartDateTime <= dateadd(HOUR, -7, GETDATE())
```

And additionaly I would like to display a row for the actual shift --> here I have some problems.
There a three shifts.
Night Shift: from: 05:45 - 13:45
early shift: from: 13:45 - 21:45
late shift: from : 21:45 - 05:45

Table:

```
IntervalStartDateTime
2017-03-28 15:30:00.000
2017-03-28 15:30:00.000
2017-03-28 15:30:00.000
2017-03-28 15:30:00.000
2017-03-28 15:30:00.000
```

How can I get the actual shift value?
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: To confirm, you are asking for a row that shows all Machines volume from the current shift?

Comment: yes, I mean the current shift data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try -

```
WHERE ( IntervalStartTime >= CASE
                                 WHEN CONVERT( TIME, GETDATE() ) < '05:45:00' THEN CONVERT( DATE, DATEADD( DAY, -1, GETDATE() ) ) + CAST( '21:45:00' AS DATETIME )
                                 WHEN CONVERT( TIME, GETDATE() ) < '13:45:00' THEN CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE() ) + CAST( '05:45:00' AS DATETIME )
                                 WHEN CONVERT( TIME, GETDATE() ) < '21:45:00' THEN CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE() ) + CAST( '13:45:00' AS DATETIME )
                                 ELSE                                              CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE() ) + CAST( '21:45:00' AS DATETIME )
                             END )
```

Note : This is my first time trying SQL-Server, but I'm going to have start sometime I guess.  :)

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Further Reading...

[combining Date and Time fields to DateTime, SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289753/combining-date-and-time-fields-to-datetime-sql-server-2008)

[How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Answer (score 0):

For the current shift...

```
with WorkByShift as
(
select OtherFields,
       case
         when cast(IntervalStartDateTime as time) < '05:45:00' then 1
         when cast(IntervalStartDateTime as time) < '13:45:00' then 2
         when cast(IntervalStartDateTime as time) < '21:45:00' then 3
         else 1
       end as ShiftNo
from MyTable
)
select WBS.*
from WorkByShift  WBS
where ShiftNo = case
                 when cast(GETDATE() as time) < '05:45:00' then 1
                 when cast(GETDATE() as time) < '13:45:00' then 2
                 when cast(GETDATE() as time) < '21:45:00' then 3
                 else 1
                end
and IntervalStartDateTime > dateadd(HOUR, -16, getdate())
```